# In server-side Blazor, how to cancel a long-running background task of a page or component?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Say I have a long running task that I've initialized and started from the OnInitializedAsync() method of my page class which is derived from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase. I use it to collect data and it updates the Ui from time to time, which works quite fine.

But at some point I'll need to get rid of that background task. When the clients changes to another page or leaves the web app, I'd like to cancel my task so it wont keep on running for good.  I don't find an appropriate lifecycle method.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I found a hint on https://blazor-university.com/components/component-lifecycles
"Although this isn’t strictly one of the ComponentBase’s lifecycle methods, if a component implements IDisposable then Blazor will execute Dispose once the component is removed from its parent’s render tree."
Is that the way to go?

Comment: Hi, have a look at IDisposable. As showing here in this tutorial https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop/blob/master/docs/03-show-order-status.md (almost on the bottom of the site)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a sample to cancel a task using a `CancellationTokenSource`

```cs
@using System.Threading
@inject HttpClient _httpClient
@implement IDisposable

...

@code {
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    private IEnumerable<Data> _data;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("api/data", _cancellationTokenSource.Token)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        _data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Data>>(content);
    }

    // cancel the task we the component is destroyed
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
         _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
         _cancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just today I was thinking about to create a global token to cancel all "remote requests" on SPA dispose.

Comment: @daniherrera I think it's useless because all your references will be disposed by the DI container, but never tried.

Comment: I have some async task that ended with `StateHasChanged`. Some times I navigate to another SPA and goes to previous one when async finished and wants to render page again. I hope to solve it using tokens.

Comment: Should be @implements